# Add dynamic content to static Nuxtjs site

Tags: nuxt.js, static-site

I created a static site for my business using Nuxtjs with a counter that keeps a running total of how many trees have been planted. Is there a way to update this counter without rebuilding the site every few minutes? Ideally, I'd like it to get the new total every time the page is loaded. Since this is the only dynamic value on the site I thought a static site would be the best option but should it be moved to an SSR site?

Comment: how do you update the tree count if not manually? do you have a file that gets automatically updated or something?

Comment: What is your current configuration? Do you need SEO for this counter or it can be purely done with JS? We lack some context here.

Comment: I ended up figuring this out. Since it's a public endpoint, I just had to create an async method, fetch the endpoint and then change the dom element that held the tree amount. I called this method in mounted()

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about SEO, you can stick with CSR (Client Side Rendering). Otherwise, use SSR (Server Side Rendering).

To update the counter, you can wrap it into a component and then update the component at periodic times (i.e every one-minute fetching data from rest API), without refreshing the whole page.